# How can I run cpuminer-multi mining package with mosix clustering package under linux

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, mining, mosix

When I run 'cpuminer-multi' package for 'xmr' digital coin mining in Ubuntu Linux under 'Mosix-4.4.4' clustering package with two node, after run that with under command, this **error message** appears for me:

> Using JSON-RPC 2.0
>   workio thread create failed

**command**:

```
$ ./mosrun -e ./minerd -a cryptonight -p stratum+tcp://frankfurt-1.xmrpool.net:5555 - u MY_WALLET_ADDRESS -p MY PASSWORD
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: tanx for your comment